# Marklogic Wrong count and Facet result Xquery

Tags: marklogic

Calling `search:search` doesn't return expected facet result counts. Below are two example files and the code I used.

Page1.xml

```
<pages xmlns="http://marklogic.com/docs">
  <page>
    <elementNode>data1</elementNode>
    <textNode>text1</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data2</elementNode>
    <textNode>text2</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data3</elementNode>
    <textNode>text3</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data4</elementNode>
    <textNode>text4</textNode>
  </page>
</pages>
```

Page2.xml

```
<pages xmlns="http://marklogic.com/docs">
  <page>
    <elementNode>data5</elementNode>
    <textNode>text5</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data6</elementNode>
    <textNode>text6</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data7</elementNode>
    <textNode>text7</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data8</elementNode>
    <textNode>text8</textNode>
  </page>
</pages>
```

Also I have created an element range index on `<elementNode>`. Now I executed following XQuery with searchText "**text1**"

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace ts= "http://marklogic.com/docs";

import module namespace search ="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare variable $options :=  
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <searchable-expression xmlns:ex="http://marklogic.com/docs">//ex:page</searchable-expression>
    <grammar>
      <starter strength="30" apply="grouping" delimiter=")">(</starter>
      <starter strength="40" apply="prefix" element="cts:not-query">NOT</starter>
      <joiner strength="10" apply="infix" element="cts:or-query" tokenize="word">OR</joiner>
      <joiner strength="20" apply="infix" element="cts:and-query" tokenize="word">AND</joiner>
      <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint">:</joiner>
    </grammar>
    <constraint name="elementNode">
      <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" type="xs:string">
        <facet-option>limit=1000</facet-option>
        <element ns="http://marklogic.com/docs" name="elementNode"/>
        <searchable-expression xmlns:ex="http://marklogic.com/clover/docs-xml">//ex:elementNode</searchable-expression>
      </range>
    </constraint>
  </options>;

let $searchResult := search:search("text1", $options)
return $searchResult
```

Which produces this result:

```
<search:response xmlns="" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <search:result index="1" uri="Page1.xml" path="fn:doc(&quot;Page1.xml&quot;)/*:pages/*:page[1]">
    <search:snippet>
      <search:match path="fn:doc(&quot;Page1.xml&quot;)/*:pages/*:page[1]/*:textNode">
        <search:highlight>text1</search:highlight>
      </search:match>
    </search:snippet>
  </search:result>
  <search:facet name="elementNode">
    <search:facet-value name="data1" count="1">data1</search:facet-value>
    <search:facet-value name="data2" count="1">data2</search:facet-value>
    <search:facet-value name="data3" count="1">data3</search:facet-value>
    <search:facet-value name="data4" count="1">data4</search:facet-value>
  </search:facet>
</search:response>
```

Now I'm seeing a problem in `facet-result`. It should return only one facet value i.e. **data1** from **page1** since only **page1** has the desired search expression "**text1**". Instead `facet-result` giving me result of all textNode values from the whole document. Please help me -- How we can restrict this? Also, count is giving me for whole document but what I want is page count match.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant XQuery code?

Comment: @grtjn I alreday provided sample code thanks for response.

Comment: Sorry, must have overlooked the scroll-bar. Bit large code example, I chunked it a bit..

Answer (score 1):

Indexes point to documents or fragments, not elements. This is similar to an RDBMS, in which indexes point to rows. Your sample XML and code suggests that you are thinking of each document as something like a relational table. Instead think of documents as rows.

If the example code is similar to the real application, I might refactor the documents so that each 'page' element becomes its own document.

Also, it's bad practice to create your own content using a namespace like `http://marklogic.com/docs`. MarkLogic might decide to use that namespace in some future release, which could cause problems for you. Select a namespace that you have a reasonable expectation of controlling.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I understand your point of wrong namespacing but its not in real application its just in this sample code also due to unavoidable reasons i can't refactor the document as you suggested is there any other way to get count of all present elementNode index count for given search query. I really stuck in this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You use a searchable-expression, which causes search results to be portioned to those elements. Unfortunately that is not the case for facet counts, as mblakele explains. His suggestion of putting the page elements in their own document is one of two possible solutions here. The other one is defining the page element as fragment root. You can do so in the Admin interface of MarkLogic. You can find it among the database properties.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks It working fine as expected after configuration now i am getting counts and facets per page. is there any setting so that i can use this dynamically because it will be user's choice to search on whole xml [under pages] or page fragment?

Comment: @user1660340 Not entirely confident, but you could try dropping the searchable-expression dynamically from the search options, that should have more or less the effect you are looking for. Changing fragmentation need reindexation, so can't be done at 'runtime'..

Comment: Even if you change the searchable expressions at runtime, the indexes will still point to whatever the fragments happen to be. That will affect facet counts, etc. To have it both ways, you would have to store the content both ways: as page-level documents and as multipage documents. That's possible, but can be tricky to implement. You might need to store the full documents under one namespace and the page-level documents under another namespace, with a field for each.

Comment: @grtjn : i tried your option to remove searchble-expression at runtime but still facets counts coming per page as explained by  mblakele but no problem i can live with it because other things are working fine as expected. But some problems still exist which i want to fix : (1) without searchable-expression it giving me search-result per file which is expected but total attribute with search:response which i want to use for pagination still giving me total page count instead of total file count. is there any workaround of it? Guys waiting for your response.

Comment: @user1660340 Not quite sure I understand what you mean with total attribute giving total page count. Perhaps open a new question about that?