# MarkLogic : Wrong total Count

Tags: marklogic

I have the two following XML files:

**Page1.xml**

```
<pages xmlns="http://marklogic.com/docs">
  <page>
    <elementNode>data1</elementNode>
    <textNode>text1</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data1</elementNode>
    <textNode>text1</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data3</elementNode>
    <textNode>text3</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data4</elementNode>
    <textNode>text4</textNode>
  </page>
<pages>
```

**Page2.xml**

```
<pages xmlns="http://marklogic.com/docs">
  <page>
    <elementNode>data1</elementNode>
    <textNode>text1</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data2</elementNode>
    <textNode>text3</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data3</elementNode>
    <textNode>text5</textNode>
  </page>
  <page>
    <elementNode>data4</elementNode>
    <textNode>text6</textNode>
  </page>
<pages>
```

I have created an element range index on "elementNode" and also defined the "page" element as a fragment root. I executed the following xquery with searchText "text1"

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace ts= "http://marklogic.com/docs";

import module namespace search ="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare variable $options :=  
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <grammar>
      <starter strength="30" apply="grouping" delimiter=")">(</starter>
      <starter strength="40" apply="prefix" element="cts:not-query">NOT</starter>
      <joiner strength="10" apply="infix" element="cts:or-query" tokenize="word">OR</joiner>
      <joiner strength="20" apply="infix" element="cts:and-query" tokenize="word">AND</joiner>
      <joiner strength="50" apply="constraint">:</joiner>
    </grammar>
    <constraint name="elementNode">
      <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" type="xs:string">
        <facet-option>limit=1000</facet-option>
        <element ns="http://marklogic.com/docs" name="elementNode"/>
      </range>
    </constraint>
  </options>;
let $searchResult := search:search("text1", $options)
return $searchResult
```

After executing the query I got the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<search:response total="3" start="1" page-length="10" xmlns="" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <search:result index="1" uri="/content/C/Documents and Settings/vimleshm/Desktop/abc.xml" path="fn:doc(&quot;/content/C/Documents and Settings/vimleshm/Desktop/abc.xml&quot;)" score="22784" confidence="0.451657" fitness="0.663945">
    <search:snippet>
      <search:match path="fn:doc(&quot;/content/C/Documents and Settings/vimleshm/Desktop/abc.xml&quot;)/*:pages/*:page[1]">
        <search:highlight>text1</search:highlight>
      </search:match>
      <search:match path="fn:doc(&quot;/content/C/Documents and Settings/vimleshm/Desktop/abc.xml&quot;)/*:pages/*:page[2]">
        <search:highlight>text1</search:highlight>
      </search:match>
    </search:snippet>
  </search:result>
  <search:result index="2" uri="/content/C/Documents and Settings/vimleshm/Desktop/abc1.xml" path="fn:doc(&quot;/content/C/Documents and Settings/vimleshm/Desktop/abc1.xml&quot;)" score="22784" confidence="0.451657" fitness="0.663945">
    <search:snippet>
      <search:match path="fn:doc(&quot;/content/C/Documents and Settings/vimleshm/Desktop/abc1.xml&quot;)/*:pages/*:page[1]">
        <search:highlight>text1</search:highlight>
      </search:match>
    </search:snippet>
  </search:result>
  <search:facet name="elementNode">
    <search:facet-value name="data1" count="3">data1</search:facet-value>
  </search:facet>
  <search:qtext>text1</search:qtext>
  <search:metrics>
    <search:query-resolution-time>PT0S</search:query-resolution-time>
    <search:facet-resolution-time>PT0.015S</search:facet-resolution-time>
    <search:snippet-resolution-time>PT0S</search:snippet-resolution-time>
    <search:total-time>PT0.015S</search:total-time>
  </search:metrics>
</search:response>
```

Now as you can see here the "total" attribute of `search:response` is "3" here because I have defined "page" as a fragment root [[Marklogic Wrong count and Facet result Xquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435620/marklogic-wrong-count-and-facet-result-xquery]). Is there any way to get the correct total count, which would be "2" here since "text1" exists only in Page1.xml and Page2.xml? Also, I got facet "data2" with count "3", which should be "2" since it exists in two XML files as in the previous case. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the fragment root to `<pages>` (or to nothing, which will default to fragmenting on the root of each XML document), and then there will be 2 hits: one with 2 matches in Page1.xml and one with 1 match in Page2.xml. However, if you set the fragment root to `<page>` as you have done, search treats each of those elements as its own document, and it will count `<page>` instead of `<pages>`.

Simply, result counts will reflect the number of fragment hits. So the question is really what do you want to count? Documents or `<page>`s?

Comment: actually it will be user's choice he/she can search in  whole document or in individual page and accordingly our query should return output. So if user's choice to search in whole document count result should be "2"· Please suggest

Comment: @user1660340 You have a few options. 1) You can fragment on `<page>` and change the options node based on user input: `<searchable-expression>//pages</searchable-expression>`. However, this number could be off by a lot - only fragments will be counted accurately. 2) You can fragment on both `<page>` and `<pages>`, but fragmenting on elements with ancestor/descendant relationships could potentially cause other problems with your application. 3) Duplicate the content, breaking up the `<page>` elements into documents. This will always be accurate.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution (1) but is still giving me total count "3" [fragment count] while i were expecting count "2" since only 2 xml file have same match.

Comment: @user1660340 As I mentioned, only fragments will be counted accurately. If you have thousands of documents the count will probably be more accurate, but not 100%. 2) could be a quick fix but cause problems down the road, and I think 3) is your only safe bet.